# See if user has logged in

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt

I am working with some inherited code and don't have a full understanding of how the JWT auth works, so please bear with me.

I have a login page where a user enters a password to see protected content. It then directs to another page. That part is fine.

What I want to do now is be able to display content on other pages if they have entered the password. I tried checking for a token and got it to show in console.log on the login redirect, but it's not showing up when I look at other pages. I know it's there because I can see it in my cookies settings.

So... how do I check for it so I can display content conditionally on other pages? Thanks in advance.

```
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const exjwt = require('express-jwt');

    module.exports = {
      // INstantiating the express-jwt middleware
      loginPost: function(req, res) {
        const jwtMW = exjwt({
          secret: 'keyboard cat 4 ever'
        });
        let users = [
          {
              id: 1,
              username: 'test1'

          },
          {
              id: 2,
              username: 'test2',
              password: 'asdf12345'
          }
        ];
        const { username, password } = req.body;
        // console.log("user" , username);
        // Use your DB ORM logic here to find user and compare password

        // Finds first username and password match in users array (assumes usernames are unique)
        var user = users.find(u => username == u.username );
        if (user) { // User credentials matched (are valid)
            let token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id, username: user.username }, 'keyboard cat 4 ever', { expiresIn: 129600 }); // Sigining the token
            res.json({
                sucess: true,
                err: null,
                token
            });
        } else { // User credentials did not match (are not valid) or no user with this username/password exists
            res.status(401).json({
                sucess: false,
                token: null,
                err: 'Username or password is incorrect'
            });
        }
      }
    };

    class Login extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
            this.decode = this.decode.bind(this);
            this.Auth = new AuthService();
        }
        render() {
            // console.log('this login', this);

            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <Grid textAlign='center' style={{ height: '475px', marginBottom: '300px' }} verticalAlign='middle'>
                        <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 450}}>
                            <Header as='h3' textAlign='center' style={{ marginBottom: '30px', marginTop: '190px'}}>
                                {/* <Image src='/logo.png' />  */}
                                Please enter the password to view this content.
                            </Header>
                            <Form size='large' onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
                                <Segment raised>
                                    <Form.Input fluid icon='lock' type='password' name="username" iconPosition='left' placeholder='password' onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                    {/* <Form.Input
                                        fluid
                                        name="password"
                                        icon='lock'
                                        iconPosition='left'
                                        placeholder='Password'
                                        type='password'
                                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    /> */}

                                    <Button className="seeAllWinesBtn" size='small'>
                                        <p className="seeAllWinesText" fluid size='large'>
                                            Login
                                </p></Button>
                                </Segment>
                            </Form>
                            <Header as='h5' textAlign='center' style={{ marginTop: '50px', marginBottom: '100px'}}>
                                This section is for clients only. To gain access, contact your sales rep or the order desk at orders@winewise.biz.
                            </Header>
                            <Link to='/'>
                            <Button> Back to Home
                                </Button>
                                </Link>
                        </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid>
                </Fragment>
            );
        }

        handleChange(e) {
            this.setState(
                {
                    [e.target.name]: e.target.value
                }
            )
            // console.log(this);
        }

        handleFormSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            this.Auth.login(this.state.username,this.state.password)
                .then(res =>{

                    // console.log('referrer', document.referrer);
                    // const redirRoute = document.referrer.split('://')[1].split('/');
                    // console.log("route:" , redirRoute);
                    const newLocation = sessionStorage.getItem('referrer');
                    sessionStorage.removeItem('referrer');
                this.props.history.replace(newLocation);
                //window.history.back();

                })
                .catch(err => {
                    alert(err);
                })
        }

        decode(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.Auth.loggedIn()
        }
    }

    export default Login;

import decode from 'jwt-decode';
export default class AuthService {
    // Initializing important variables
    constructor() {
        this.fetch = this.fetch.bind(this) // React binding stuff
        this.login = this.login.bind(this)
        this.getProfile = this.getProfile.bind(this)
    }

    login(username, password) {
        // Get a token from api server using the fetch api
        // console.log('logindomain', this.domain);
        return this.fetch(`/api/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password
            })
        }).then(res => {
            this.setToken(res.token) // Setting the token in localStorage
            return Promise.resolve(res);
        })
    }

    loggedIn() {
        // Checks if there is a saved token and it's still valid
        const token = this.getToken() // GEtting token from localstorage
        // console.log('token', token);
        const loggedIn = !!token && !this.isTokenExpired(token);
        !loggedIn && !sessionStorage.getItem('referrer') && sessionStorage.setItem('referrer', window.location.pathname);
        return loggedIn; // handwaiving here
    }

    isTokenExpired(token) {
        try {
            const decoded = decode(token);
            // console.log("decoded", decoded);
            if (decoded.exp < Date.now() / 1000) { // Checking if token is expired. N
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (err) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    setToken(idToken) {
        // Saves user token to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', idToken)
    }

    getToken() {
        // Retrieves the user token from localStorage
        return localStorage.getItem('id_token')
    }

    logout() {
        // Clear user token and profile data from localStorage
        localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    }

    getProfile() {
        // Using jwt-decode npm package to decode the token
        return decode(this.getToken());
    }


    fetch(url, options) {
        // performs api calls sending the required authentication headers
        const headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }

        // Setting Authorization header
        // Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxx
        if (this.loggedIn()) {
            headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + this.getToken()
        }

        return fetch(url, {
            headers,
            ...options
        })
            .then(this._checkStatus)
            .then(response => response.json())
    }

    _checkStatus(response) {
        // raises an error in case response status is not a success
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) { // Success status lies between 200 to 300
            return response
        } else {
            var error = new Error(response.statusText)
            error.response = response
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well, you need to save the JWT token somewhere and then read if that token is saved. Also you want to use it on subsequent requests

Comment: okay @JohnRuddell thanks. I added more code in the post above. I believe it saves the token in localStorage with 
    setToken(idToken) {
        // Saves user token to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', idToken)
    }

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment, one of the most common solutions is to store the token in a browser's localStorage, which you then can access with `localStorage.getItem(item-name)`.  You'll have to verify that token with your server, however, to ensure that has not expired and is a valid token to begin with, so you'd need some kind of service on your back end that will accept the token, verify it and return its status so that you can make decisions about rendering/access on your front end.